# My sketch is not working as intended

Tags: programming

I am a beginner with Arduino. I am doing something to cool down my room temperature using an exhaust fan and cooler through relays. I am trying to reduce the temperature initially using an exhaust fan and wait for 10 minutes to see if the temperature reduced to a set range. If not, the exhaust fan is turned off and the rest of the cooling is done by the cooler.

At the beginning of the program all goes well: it turns on the exhaust fan and waits 10 minutes and if it's not dropping, it transfers the job to the cooler. But after one cycle, when the temperature increases, the cooler is turned on directly, without the exhaust fan urning on, or waiting for 10 minutes and things. I tried a lot but I can't understand what is happening. Please suggest something to solve the problem.

```
#include <dht.h>

dht DHT;

#define DHT1_PIN 7 // dht11 connected to pin 7

int exhaustpin = 4; // set pin for exhaust fan relay
int coolerpin = 5; // set pin for cooler relay
boolean exhaust;
void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(exhaustpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(coolerpin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(exhaustpin,HIGH );
  digitalWrite(coolerpin,HIGH );
  exhaust= LOW; 

}
void loop()
{

    DHT.read11(DHT1_PIN);
  Serial.print(" MY Room Temperature = ");
  Serial.println(DHT.temperature);
  Serial.print("MY Room Humidity = ");
  Serial.println(DHT.humidity);
 delay(500); 
  int  roomtemp =DHT.temperature;
  static unsigned long interval;
  long interval;
  if (exhaust== LOW){
  if ((roomtemp>=30)&&(digitalRead(coolerpin)==HIGH )){
    digitalWrite(exhaustpin,LOW ); // if temperature increses above 30 the exhaust starts to work
     interval = millis();
  }
  }
   if (digitalRead(exhaustpin)==LOW){
     exhaust= !exhaust;
 if ((millis()-interval) >= 600000){
    digitalWrite(coolerpin,LOW );
    digitalWrite(exhaustpin,HIGH );   // after the starting of exhaust fan it wait for 10 minutes ,then it turn 
                                      // on the cooler and turns off the exhaust fan
       }
   }
  if (roomtemp<28){
    digitalWrite(coolerpin,HIGH );
     digitalWrite(exhaustpin,HIGH );
     exhaust= !exhaust;
   // i am trying here to start cooling the room with my exhaust fan
   // then wait 10 minutes ,if it is still not less than 28 degrees turn on the cooler to do the cooling
   // and turn off the exhaust fan
   }
  }
```

Comment: FYI you may want to fix indentation, it will help a lot with making the flow of the program clear. I edited your post with that.

Comment: Code doesn't compile.

Comment: I doubt this code works at all. The DHT object is not initialized...

Comment: The DTH11 working part is fine.All other functions are going as planed but except the Time schedule

Comment: What should happen when the temperature drops after the cooler run to 28 and then again grows over 30? Try the fan again? Please show all the sketch after correction.

Comment: yes my intention is as you said

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (digitalRead(exhaustpin) == LOW) {
    static unsigned long interval = millis();
    if ((millis() - interval) >= 600000) {
      digitalWrite(coolerpin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(exhaustpin, HIGH);
      // after the starting of exhaust fan it wait for 10 minutes, then it turns on
      // the cooler and turns off the exhaust fan
    }
  }
```

`interval` is only ever set once. So 10 minutes after it is first set it will remain over 10 minutes.

The simplest fix is to set `interval` to `millis()` when you set `exhaustpin` to low:

```
if ((roomtemp>=30)&&(digitalRead(coolerpin)==HIGH)) {
  digitalWrite(exhaustpin,LOW );
  // if temperature increses above 30 the exhaust starts to work
  interval = millis();
}
```

Comment: i tried your help but now the cooler pin is not turning on after the 10 minute on the first time

Comment: `interval` has to be a global. You can't create it every time you enter the if clause...

Comment: can you be more specific i can't get my head behind it.

Comment: Put `unsigned long interval = 0;` on the line before loop() and then when you want to assign it, leave out the `unsigned long` and just say `interval = millis()`

Comment: still the problem is not solved , the interval is not working now